# CasperJs, how to fill a form that only have a class, not a name and not an id?

Tags: casperjs

I want to fill this form, but i dont know how to do it since it only have a classname.
All the examples i saw have an id or a name, to fill the form and submit it, please help.

```
    <form class="header_form" method="post" action="">
  <div class="lgn-items">
      <div class="login_item">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" tabindex="1" class="inputtext" id="email" />
      </div>
        <div class="login_item" >
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password"  name="password"  tabindex="2" class="inputtext" id="pass" />
       </div>
        <div class="lgn-add">
          <a href="/register.html" class="forgot_pass ">Registration</a> <span>|</span>
          <a href="/forgot.html" class="forgot_pass alt">Forgot your password ?</a>
          <div class="rembo">
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1" /> Remember me
        </div>
        </div>
   </div>   
    <div class="login_item lgn-btn" >
        <input type="submit" name="login_button" value="Login" tabindex="3" class="login" />

    </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access to your form using any selector. In your case you to it like this.

```
casper.then(function () {
        casper.fill('form.header_form', {
        /** Your parameters here **/
    }, true);
});
```